# INSERT FROM syntax

Tags: android, sql

logcat

```
    12-07 12:24:30.394 7246-7246/me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "FROM": syntax error
    12-07 12:24:30.396 7246-7246/me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab, PID: 7246
 android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "FROM": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT FROM OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount)VALUES('02','Nasi Goreng','5','6','5');
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
     at me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab.Database.Database.addToCart(Database.java:61)
     at me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab.FoodDetail$1.onClick(FoodDetail.java:55)
     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
    12-07 12:24:30.420 1589-1839/? E/ActivityManager: Found activity ActivityRecord{dc9c9ab u0 me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab/.MainActivity t99 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord{226ea2 7246:me.jaxbot.appfoodgrab/u0a82}
    12-07 12:38:42.780 2368-2922/? E/NetworkScheduler: ignoring stale queue check message
```

My coding

```
  public void addToCart (Order order)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT FROM OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice(),
                order.getDiscount());
        db.execSQL(query);

    }
```

Comment: You are using insert queries wrong: it should be "insert into ...." rather than "insert from ...."

Comment: Please fully explain the what problem and original objective are -- as well as what you've already tried -- in your question. Otherwise you'll probably get fewer useful answers than hoped for. For the record, the first comment above probably fixes the issue (or at least gets you past the specified error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is with the SQL query.Its like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME [(column1, column2, column3,...columnN)]  
VALUES (value1, value2, value3,...valueN);
```

So for your case

```
String query = String.format("INSERT INTO OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');", order.getProductId(), order.getProductName(), order.getQuantity(), order.getPrice(), order.getDiscount()); db.execSQL(query);
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 2):

Your `query` is wrong

use **`INSERT INTO`** instead of **`INSERT FROM`**

Try this

```
public void addToCart (Order order)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query = String.format("INSERT INTO  OrderDetail(ProductId,ProductName,Quantity,Price,Discount)VALUES('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');",
                order.getProductId(),
                order.getProductName(),
                order.getQuantity(),
                order.getPrice(),
                order.getDiscount());
        db.execSQL(query);

    }
```